# How to include an already existing extension from github into my main index.html code?

Tags: javascript, json, autodesk-forge

I am trying to implement an extension into my main code. I tried to copy the code and make my own but this didnt work or the extension was not visualised, I dont have a clue. This is the github page with the extension I would like to use: [link] (https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.IoT) Thank you in advance!

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- The Viewer CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/style.min.css" type="text/css">

    <!-- Developer CSS -->
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #MyViewerDiv {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #F0F8FF;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- The Viewer will be instantiated here -->
    <div id="MyViewerDiv"></div>

    <!-- The Viewer JS -->
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/viewers/6.*/viewer3D.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Developer JS -->
    <script>
        var viewerApp;
        var options = {
            env: 'AutodeskProduction',
            getAccessToken: function(onGetAccessToken) {
                //
                // TODO: Replace static access token string below with call to fetch new token from your backend
                // Both values are provided by Forge's Authentication (OAuth) API.
                //
                // Example Forge's Authentication (OAuth) API return value:
                // {
                //    "access_token": "<YOUR_APPLICATION_TOKEN>",
                //    "token_type": "Bearer",
                //    "expires_in": 86400
                // }
                //
                var accessToken = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJSRmcyZEh1TXFkemVuSjl2eng2ZWFScnhYRDczZ2RMMSIsImV4cCI6MTU2NzA3MjIxNywic2NvcGUiOlsiZGF0YTpyZWFkIiwiZGF0YTp3cml0ZSIsImRhdGE6Y3JlYXRlIiwiYnVja2V0OnJlYWQiLCJidWNrZXQ6Y3JlYXRlIl0sImF1ZCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYXV0b2Rlc2suY29tL2F1ZC9qd3RleHA2MCIsImp0aSI6Ill0Ykozb0hxWDhIbGJMS0p2UDVkWWhEVEhPeUx1TXVxQWo4cnZSOW5LR2FIZmY4YmkweVQ4N2UzVXZvd2g0TWIifQ.Rq7TsewQlXl0VnSfzaR0bw7Vxgh4EOSf9xD9jqfg0b4';
                var expireTimeSeconds = 60 * 30;
                onGetAccessToken(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds);
            }

        };
        let config3d = {
          extensions: ['Autodesk.InViewerSearch']
        }; 

        var documentId = 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6amFuc3NlbnNfMjcwODIwMTkvSUZDJTIwU2NoZXBlbmRvbWxhYW4ucnZ0';
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized(){
            viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('MyViewerDiv');
            viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D, config3d);
            viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
        });

        function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {

            // We could still make use of Document.getSubItemsWithProperties()
            // However, when using a ViewingApplication, we have access to the **bubble** attribute,
            // which references the root node of a graph that wraps each object from the Manifest JSON.
            var viewables = viewerApp.bubble.search({'type':'geometry'});
            if (viewables.length === 0) {
                console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
                return;
            }

            // Choose any of the avialble viewables
            viewerApp.selectItem(viewables[0].data, onItemLoadSuccess, onItemLoadFail);
        }

        function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
            console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
        }

        function onItemLoadSuccess(viewer, item) {
            console.log('onItemLoadSuccess()!');
            console.log(viewer);
            console.log(item);

            // Congratulations! The viewer is now ready to be used.
            console.log('Viewers are equal: ' + (viewer === viewerApp.getCurrentViewer()));
        }

        function onItemLoadFail(errorCode) {
            console.error('onItemLoadFail() - errorCode:' + errorCode);
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to build this extension before you can use it - see this repo [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions) to build the extensions separately.

But this extension is locked in with React so you will need to strip the React bits off before you can with your frameworkless plain old HTML.

We are working on a revamp of both RCDB and Extension Library just to isolate the extensions from unnecessary dependencies like React - will come back to update this answer once that's done.